# Adding an html document to an article

Tags: article, html

I'm trying to add an html document to an article document and i don't seem to find a way. Anyone can help?
Thank you all very much in advance !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please be more specific! How tried you and failed? Show also an short example of your used TeX code and html file. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: I simply have an html file, that i want to show up in the document, the way it is shown when i open it with my browser. Does not work as a figure and i can't seem to find anything else that would help me.

Comment: None of the TeX engines has a HTML renderer. So ...

Comment: If you don't want to convert it to LaTeX, you could either turn the rendered HTML into a PDF and include that or you could attach or link it and have it open in a web browser.